# How to use Burp Suite together with The BodgeIt Store?

Tags: proxy, apache, burp-suite

The BodgeIt Store is a vulnerable web application for studying web development security. It can be downloaded from the internet and installed locally on your computer as a docket container. This web application runs on your own computer through Apache tomcat on port 8080. You can go to http://localhost:8080/bodgeit/ to access the application. After that you can try to perform various hacks on it.

I want to use Burp Suite for intercepting traffic from the browser into the server, for tampering the data in order to hack the application. The problem is that Burp Suite's proxy listener normally runs on interface 127.0.0.1 port 8080. However, because there is already an application running on port 8080 (Apache tomcat for the BodgeIt Store) I cannot start up the proxy listener of the Burp Suite, which means that I cannot intercept the traffic which goes to the server.

The message given by Burp Suite is:

> No proxy listeners are currently running - go to the Options tab to enable a listener

I can add the listener on interface 127.0.0.1 port 8080 but I cannot run it. How can I get the proxy listener to run using Burp Suite and have it intercept HTTP messages going to the Apache tomcat web server?

Comment: This is not a security question, it's a question on how to set up the BodgeIt store. But the gist of it is, you have to configure TBS in a way to run on a port other than 8080. Furthermore, burp has trouble intercepting on `localhost`. You need to make a second entry (e.g. `store.local`) that points to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: You can also run Burp’s proxy on a port other than 8080, that way you don’t have to change your docker image.

Comment: @JohnDeters I tried that, and now the proxy listener runs successfully, but it's not picking up anything from the BodgeIt store.

Comment: You still have to configure your browser to use the new port for its proxy.

Comment: After looking at the source to BodgeIt, i'm guessing you only have to change the port number, not the host binding, which should already be 127.0.0.1 in tomcat.